# How to send mail via console on OpenBSD using a Gmail account?

Tags: openbsd, msmtp, gmail

There is a certificate error:

```
# echo "hello" | msmtp -a default DESTINATION@gmail.com
msmtp: TLS certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /root/.msmtprc)
#
```

In the config file:

```
# cat .msmtprc
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile        ~/.msmtp.log

# Gmail
account         gmail
host            smtp.gmail.com
port            587
from            FOOBAR@gmail.com
user            FOOBAR
password        BARFOO

# Set a default account
account default : gmail
#
```

But I have the cert there!

```
# uname -mrs
OpenBSD 6.0 amd64
#
# cksum /etc/ssl/cert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
1384454833 189049 /etc/ssl/cert.pem
1384454833 189049 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#
```

The log only says:

```
# cat .msmtp.log
Aug 22 20:43:14 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=FOOBAR from=FOOBAR@gmail.com recipients=DESTINATION@gmail.com errormsg='TLS certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
#
```

Why couldn't it recognize the cert?

Comment: Are the permissions on the cert file correct?

Comment: It is run by root, but will check it, thx

Comment: Why not use the built-in smtpd(8) as a relay and mail(1) instead of a third-party program?  smtpd will talk to Gmail and you can run mail from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and change `tls_trust_file` to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`.